# Use of present perfect passive "has not being" or "was not being"

Tags: grammar, phrases

> Industrial sector has not being attractive enough to absorb excess labour in the agricultural sector.

(Wanted to explain an Ongoing process from past to present)

> Industrial sector was not being attractive enough to absorb excess labour in the agricultural sector.

(Wanted to explain what had happened during a period of twenty years, which ended in 2010)

I understand that, I can use present perfect tense in explaining something which has happened in the past which continues to the present. So, i used 'has not being' as the passive form of past present perfect tense, in the first sentence. (Not quite sure though)

In the second sentence, the process had begun some time in the past, continued for a period and ended.  I was just wondering whether I have to 'had not being' in the second sentence.

Thank you.

Comment: Asking if a sentence is correct is off-topic here. To avoid the question being deleted, can you add anything to it? What is the reason you think they sentences might be right or wrong? What did your research say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither sentence uses the perfect, nor the passive:  The perfect tense is "have + past participle".

The first sentence is "has ... being"  That is "have + present participle"  And so is not correct.

The second sentence is "was ... being" That is the past continuous.  But we very rarely use past continous with adjectives. We don't say "was being attractive".

The perfect tense would be "... has not been..."  You can't use a passive voice here, because there is no transitive verb (a verb with an object).

There are other problems with your sentences.  But you should try to keep the grammar simple: either "was not attractive" or "has not been attractive".